# Sorting enum by parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

For example, there's class Contact. I want to find all contacts with pagination and specification. There is a problem with sorting contacts by contactType because hibernate tries to sort by string PHONE or FAX. But what I need is to sort by contactType nameEn or nameUk depends on current locale. Ukrainian alphabet has different positions of letters compared to English. Maybe someone can help with this?

```
public class Contact {
    ...
    @Column(length = 50)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ContactType type;
    ...
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public enum ContactType {
    PHONE("Phone", "Телефон"),
    FAX("Fax", "Факс");
    private final String nameEn;
    private final String nameUk;

    public String getName(Locale locale){
        if(Objects.equals(locale.getLanguage(), "en")){
            return nameEn;
        }
        return nameUk;
    }
}

@AllArgsConstructor
public class ContactSpecification implements Specification<Contact> {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Contact> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        final String language = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().getLanguage();
        switch (request.sortProperties()) {
            ...
            case "contactType " -> query.orderBy(
                    Objects.equals(request.sortDirection(), Direction.ASC) ?
                            criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get("type")) : criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get("type"))
            );
        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JPA/Hibernate doesn't have built-in support for the functionality you're looking for unfortunately, you can't sort enum fields this way. As alternative ideas that might help:

- DB-level changes
  You may create separate columns in your database for `nameEn` and `nameUk`, and map these columns to your `Contact` entity, so you can sort for `nameEn` instead
- Sort in-memory 
  Just get unsorted results in your application and then sort them there. Might be pretty viable if you're working with a small number of entities, but inefficient and lead to memory problems in case of large sizes. So you'll get something like:

```java
List<Contact> sortedContacts = contacts.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(contact -> contact.getType().getName(LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I hope my answer helped @Antariuz :bow: